# Phyton: How to get the average of the n largest values for each column grouped by id

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to get the mean for each column while grouped by id. But I don't get it to work as I want to.

*The data:*

```
ID       Property3   Property2   Property3
1        10.2        ...         ...
1        20.1
1        51.9
1        15.8
1        12.5
...
1203     104.4
1203     11.5
1203     19.4
1203     23.1
```

*What I got so far:*
I got those two tries. But they are both just for one column and I don't know how to do it for more then just one.:

```
data.groupby('id')['property1'].apply(lambda grp: grp.nlargest(100).mean())
1       37.897989
2       33.059432
3       34.926530
4       33.036137

data.groupby('id').agg({'property1': {lambda grp: grp.nlargest(100).mean()}})
id  property1 <lambda>
1   37.897989
2   33.059432
3   34.926530
4   33.036137
```

*What I want:*
Idealy, I would like to have a dataframe as follows:

```
ID       Property3   Property2   Property3
1        37.8        5.6         2.3
2        33.0        1.5         10.4
3        34.9        91.5        10.3
4        33.0        10.3        14.3
```

So that each row contains the mean values for the 100 biggest values for EACH column grouped by id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) with omit columns for processing all columns in DataFrame without `ID`:

```
df = data.groupby('ID').agg(lambda grp: grp.nlargest(100).mean()).reset_index()

print (df)
       ID  Property1  Property2  Property3
0     1.0       22.1       ...       ...
1  1203.0       39.6       ...       ...
```

Or specify columns after `groupby`:

```
df = (data.groupby('ID')['Property1','Property2','Property3']
          .agg(lambda grp: grp.nlargest(100).mean())
          .reset_index())
```

Comment: amazing. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Use [`GroupBy.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) with `as_index=False` 
so that `id` is a column:

```
data.groupby('id',as_index=False).agg(lambda grp: grp.nlargest(100).mean())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df['average_max'] = df.groupby('ID').agg(lambda grp: grp.nlargest(10).mean())
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply